# continuous page numbering through section breaks

Tags: ms-word

The page numbering in footer returns to 1 after every section break in my 
long document. I'm using Word 2013, odd and even page headers 
and footers.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can check out [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/741549/how-to-i-set-up-continuous-paging-in-word-across-different-sections).

Word starts page numbering over for each new section by default.

I do it slightly differently than the post above that goes through the ribbon menus, but in both methods you have to go through the document to each section's beginning.

My method:

- open up the footer (or header if that's where your page number is)
- drag-select the page number
- right-click on it
- hit `Format Page Numbers`
- click on the `Continue from Previous Section` radio button under `Page numbering`

I find this right-click method to be a little faster. Also, usually if I insert the page numbers first before I start making any new sections, this problem doesn't happen in the first place.